# Testing LightOpenID in Localhost

Tags: php, openid, wampserver, lightopenid, google-authentication

I am using LightOpenID to enable Google Authentication in my PHP web application.

However when I test the same in my local server I get the following error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled.' in C:\wamp\www\speakerdb\openid.php on line 94
( ! ) ErrorException: You must have either https wrappers or curl enabled. in C:\wamp\www\speakerdb\openid.php on line 94
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  366848  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0034  648640  LightOpenID->__construct( ) ..\index.php:4
```

This runs fine in my remote server.
I am going to use LightOpenID in each page of my application to check if user have signed in or not. I am tried giving "localhost" as domain name but get the same error.

I enabled curl un my wamp server but but pages with LightOpenID does not run when curl is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable SSL modules on both, apache and PHP configurations and check if that works:

**php.ini:**

> extension=php_openssl.dll

**apache.conf:**

> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Comment: As soon as I enabled SSL in PHP the pages stopped loading . Enabling ssl in apache does not do any harm.

Comment: Finally got rid of the error using above method and rebooting machine. Still the problem remains that LightOpenID does not return user information with domain as  Localhost

Comment: Is there a chance that it might be a logic problem on your program that is causing the problem with LightOpenID? and just to be clear, the original "Fatal Error" on the question is gone, correct?

Comment: Yes , Original fatal error is gone now, so I voted for this answer. Thanks a lot. But localhost as domain name does not work, when it goes from login page to login.php it does not validate to true. Same code works when I upload the files to my domain name and change my domain name. I am following the article [link]( http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/)

Comment: this did it! man! times like these, i feel what would i do without SO